# How to check my Mac Bluetooth Version(LMP)?

Tags: macos, unix, bluetooth

I would like to know how to check the Bluetooth version on macOS.

There have been similar questions in the past, and the answers suggested checking the `LMP Version` in the system profile to find this information.

[image]

However, in the latest macOS (`Sonoma - 14.2.1`), this method no longer seems to work. According to other posts on platforms like Reddit, it appears that this change has persisted at least until version 12.
https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/tcqbw9/unable_to_see_lmp_bluetooth_version_under_system/

I considered using terminal commands for more detailed information, but the results were similar.

```
❯ system_profiler -detailLevel full SPBluetoothDataType
Bluetooth:

      Bluetooth Controller:
          Address: 3C:06:30:0F:92:18
          State: On
          Chipset: BCM_4378
          Discoverable: Off
          Firmware Version: 21.1.527.3724
          Product ID: 0x4A01
          Supported services: 0x392039 < HFP AVRCP A2DP HID Braille LEA AACP GATT SerialPort >
          Transport: PCIe
          Vendor ID: 0x004C (Apple)
```

Wanted to check if anyone here has insights or alternative methods to determine the Bluetooth version on the latest macOS. If there's a command-line solution or any other approach that works with recent macOS versions, I would greatly appreciate the guidance.